# RestKit different value in JSON Route

Tags: json, restkit, restkit-0.20

I've searched a long time to find an answer, but the documentation and examples are very vague.

In RestKit 2.0, how do you properly have a changing URL that binds to an object and map it.

So when creating RKResponseDescriptor, you pass pathPattern that might have:

"api/:userid/something"

for example "api/233/something" or "api/533/something"

and you want :userid to change when calling getObjectsAtPath and passing that value as a parameter?

I cannot get it to change the URL when it calls GET, it will add the parameter on the end of the URL as ?userid but :userid remains in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that when using `getObjectsAtPath:parameters:success:failure:`. Instead, you should use `getObject:path:parameters:success:failure:` and then the `objectId` parameter will be filled into the path by querying the `obkect` you supply for that key.

Note that a path pattern with an object id would be expected to return details for that single object, not a list of objects.